# Describe the group automorphism of a k-automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $B = k[T]$ with $k$ a field; a $k$-automorphism of $B$ is a ring homomorphism $φ: B \to B$ that is the identity on $k$ and is an automorphism of $B$;
(i) Describe the group $Aut(B)$ of $k$-automorphism of $B$;
(ii) now do the same for the field $K = k(T)$ of rational function.

Comment: You seem to have used the same notation for the polynomial ring and the field of rational functions. Anyway, what have you tried? What could the image of $T$ under such a map be?

Answer (score 1):

Any $k$-automorphism $\phi$ of $B$ is determined completely by its effect on $T$, viz. the polynomial  $\phi(T)$  associated to the degree 1 polynomial $T$.  If    $\phi(T)$ is of degree $k$ then the image will have constants and polynomials of degree a multiple of $k$. Now you should be able figure out what choices will make $\phi$   an automorphism.

Comment: This is clear for the $k[T]$ case. But how would one prove the $k(T)$ case?