# Exercise 0.6i in Miles Reid's Commutative Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, solution-verification, automorphism-group

> Let $B=k[T]$ with $k$ a field; a *k-automorphism* of $B$ is a ring homomorphism $\phi: B\rightarrow B$ that is the identity on $k$ and is an automorphism of $B$. Describe the group $\text{Aut}_k(B)$ of $k$-automorphisms of $B$.

For $f=\sum_{i=0}^na_iT^i\in B$, since $\phi(f)=\sum_{i=0}^na_i\phi(T)^i$, the automorphism is determined by $\phi(T)$. Let therefore $\phi(T)=\sum_{i=0}^na_iT^i$. Let $c\neq 0,1$ (assume $k\neq\Bbb F_2$), since $\phi$ is $k$-automorphism $$c\phi(T)=\phi(cT)\tag{1}$$$$\sum_{i=0}^nca_iT^i=\sum_{i=0}^nc^ia_iT^i\iff\sum_{i=0}^n(c-c^i)a_iT^i=0\tag{2}$$ This gives:

$$\begin{align}(c-1)a_0=0\\(c-c)a_1=0\\(c-c^2)a_2=0\\\vdots\\(c-c^n)a_n=0\end{align}\tag{3}$$ 
Which gives $\phi(T)=a_1T$. Since $\phi(1)=1$, it follows that $a_1=1$.

Therefore $$\text{Aut}_k(B)\cong \{e\}\tag{4}$$ That is, the only $k$-automorphism is the identity, $\phi(T)=T$. Is this correct?

---

*Edit*: *I think I got it now,*

Let $\phi\in\text{Aut}_k(k[T])$, and $g=\sum_{i=0}^na_iT^i$. As $\phi(g)=\sum_{i=0}^na_i\phi(T)^i=g(\phi(T))$, we have $\phi(g)=g(\phi(T))$, that is, the automorphism $\phi$ "evaluates" any polynomial $g$ at some polynomial $\phi(T)=f$. I therefore define $\phi:=\phi_f$ to emphasize this, where $$\phi_f(g)=g(f(T))\tag{5}$$

It is clear that for $g,h\in k[T]$ (for the same reason that evaluation is a homomorphism):

- $\phi_f(g+h)=\phi_f(g)+\phi_f(h)$
- $\phi_f(gh)=\phi_f(g)\phi_f(h)$
- $\phi_f(c)=c$ for $c\in k$, that is, $\phi_f$ acts as the identity on $k$

Also $$\deg(\phi_f(g))=\deg(f)\deg(g)\tag{6}$$ As $\phi_f$ needs to be surjective we need to have $\deg(\phi_f(g))=1$ for some $g\in k[T]$, this gives $$1=\deg(f)\deg(g)\tag{7}$$ Both $\deg(f),\deg(g)\geq 0$ (integers) for $f,g\neq 0$ which gives $\deg(f)=\deg(g)=1$, thus $$\phi_f(T)=a_0+a_1T\tag{8}$$ We find the inverse: $$\phi_f^{-1}(T)=-a_0a_1^{-1}+a_1^{-1}T\tag{9}$$ which exists if and only if $a_1\neq 0$.

Thus $$\boxed{\text{Aut}_k(k[T])=\langle k\oplus k^\times, *\rangle\mid (a_0,a_1)*(b_0,b_1)=(a_0b_1+b_0,a_1b_1)}\tag{10}$$

Comment: The identity is a $k$-automorphism

Comment: @marwalix I agree, but I can't see how that helps me

Comment: @user26857 I see, I meant the trivial group when I wrote $0$. I will change it to not cause confusion.

Comment: If this means that there is only one $k$-automorphism, then you are right.

Comment: @marwalix That's definitely not correct.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748055/describe-the-group-automorphism-of-a-k-automorphism

Comment: Would someone care to explain the downvote? Where can I improve the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. "... Let $c\neq 0,1$ ..."

What if $k=F_2$?

2. "... $$c\phi(T)=\phi(cT)$$

$$\sum_{i=0}^nca_iT^i=\sum_{i=0}^nc^ia_iT^i "$$

Do you mean that $\phi(cT)=\sum_{i=0}^nc^ia_iT^i$? What if $\phi(\sum_{i=0}^na_iT^i):=\sum_{i=0}^na_i(T+1)^i$? (the inverse of this map is $\psi(\sum_{i=0}^na_iT^i):=\sum_{i=0}^na_i(T-1)^i$).

3. "... This forces $a_0=0,a_1=1,a_2=0,a_3=0,\ldots$ $

Why $a_1=1$? (and why $a_0=0$ (by 2)?).

(I understand you are not looking for the solution, but only the correctness of your "proof").

Comment: For the solution you will have to use somewhere that $\phi$ is an automorphism and not merely an endomorphism.

Comment: I mean that $\phi(T)=\sum_{i=0}^ma_iT^i$, a general polynomial. Also, wouldn't $\phi(\sum_{i=0}^na_iT^i)=\sum_{i=0}^na_i\phi(T)^i$? I get that every coefficient except $a_1$ is $0$ by comparing the two polynomials $c\phi(T)$ and $\phi(cT)$ term-wise. I don't see what I've done wrong.

Comment: If, for example, $\phi(T)=T+1$ I would get $\phi(\sum_{i=0}^na_iT^i)=\sum_{i=0}^na_i(T+1)^i$

Comment: If $\phi(\sum_{i=0}^na_iT^i):=\sum_{i=0}^na_i(T+1)^i$, then  $\phi(c\sum_{i=0}^na_iT^i)=\phi(\sum_{i=0}^nca_iT^i)=\sum_{i=0}^nca_i(T+1)^i$, while $c\phi(\sum_{i=0}^na_iT^i)=c\sum_{i=0}^na_i(T+1)^i=\sum_{i=0}^nca_i(T+1)^i$. Both terms are equal so you don't obtain anything about the $a_i$.

Comment: (+1) Thank you for your time, I think i got it now, my line (2) is wrong. I've updated my answer. Feel free to correct me!

Comment: Your welcome. Now it seems very nicely written.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some elements. Say $T\to 2T$ or $T\to T+1$. In fact, a $k$-algebra map $k[T]\to k[T]$ is determined by the image of $T$, as you said. But your condition that $\phi(\lambda T) = \lambda \phi(T)$ is automatically satisfied once you extend the definition of $\phi$ to all of $k[T]$ using the *function* $\{T\}\to k[T]$. And, as I hinted at, such a function defines an automorphism if and only if $\phi(T) $ is linear: the group of algebra automorphisms of $k[T]$ is the affine group $A(1,k)$ of maps $T\mapsto \lambda T+\mu$.

Comment: This confuses me; the map $T\mapsto T+1$ wouldn’t fix elements of $k$. Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout The map $T \to T+1$ is the map $\phi(\sum_{i=0}^na_iT^i):=\sum_{i=0}^na_i(T+1)^i$ that I wrote in my answer as an example to evidence one mistake. It clearly fixes the elements of $k$ (i.e., the degree 0 polynomials).

Comment: @A.G Maybe my understanding of *fixes* is wrong; I thought *fixes* meant that the map is the identity on $k$? Wouldn't $1\mapsto 1+1=2$? Or am I not allowed to insert values for $T$?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout "Fixes k" means that the triangle $k\to k[T]$; $k\to k[T]$; $\phi: k[T]\to k[T]$ is commutative. Your interpretation ($1\to 1+1$) is that the triangle $\phi: k[T]\to k[T]$; $k[T]\to k$, $T\to 1$; $k[T]\to k$, $T\to 1$ is commutative (I hope the "triangles" could be unserstood: it is difficult to write them in a comment).

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout No, $T$ is an element of $k[T]$. You're confusing ''fixes $k$, the constant polynomials'' with ''commutes with the evaluation maps'' $k[T]\to k$ obtained by evaluating $T$ at some scalar.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have observed that $\phi$ is determined by its value on $T$. Let us start from here.
2. For any $\alpha\in k$, the ideal $(T-\alpha)$ is maximal.
3. Apply $\phi$, one have ideals $(\phi(T)-\alpha)$.
4. These ideals are maximal.
5. Consider taking $\alpha=\phi(0)$, we get $\operatorname{deg}(\phi(T))=1$.
6. On the contrary, a $k$-endomorphism of $B$ taking $T$ to a degree one polynomial is an automorphism. (The inverse can be constructed explicitly.)