# Exercise 0.6ii in Miles Reid's Commutative Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory, solution-verification, automorphism-group

> Let $K=k(T)$ be the field of rational functions; a *k-automorphism* of $K$ is a ring homomorphism $\phi: K\rightarrow K$ that is the identity on $k$ and is an automorphism of $K$. Describe the group $\text{Aut}_k(K)$ of $k$-automorphisms of $K$.

I've found that every homomorphism looks like an evaluation $T\mapsto \phi(T)$, since for any $f,g\in k[T]$ we have

$$\phi\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)=\phi\left(\frac{\sum_{i=0}^na_iT^i}{\sum_{j=0}^mb_jT^j}\right)=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^na_i\phi(T)^i}{\sum_{j=0}^mb_j\phi(T)^j}=\frac{\phi(f)}{\phi(g)}=\frac{f(\phi(T))}{g(\phi(T))}\tag{1}$$ and that this is a homomorphism, for precisely the same reason that any evaluation is a homomorphism.

I then define $\phi:=\phi_{\frac{f}{g}}$ to map $T\mapsto\frac{f}{g}$, where $\frac{f}{g}\in K$. Since $\phi_{\frac{f}{g}}$ is an automorphism I should have an inverse $\phi^{-1}_{\frac{f}{g}}=\phi_{\frac{r}{s}}$ which maps $T\mapsto\frac{r}{s}$. This means that $$\phi_{\frac{r}{s}}\left(\phi_{\frac{f}{g}}(T)\right)=\frac{f\left(\frac{r}{s}\right)}{g\left(\frac{r}{s}\right)}=T\tag{2}$$

$$ f\left(\frac{r}{s}\right)=Tg\left(\frac{r}{s}\right)\tag{3}$$

My strategy is now to make eq. $(3)$ a polynomial equation in $k[T]$, and then compute the degree. (Similar to the first part of the [exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3540313/413677)) I multiply both sides of eq. $(3)$ by $s^{\deg(f)+\deg(g)}$.

$$f\left(\frac{r}{s}\right)s^{\deg(f)+\deg(g)}=s^{\deg(g)}\sum_{i=0}^{\deg(f)}a_is^{\deg(f)-i}r^i\tag{4}$$ The degree of the polynomial in $(4)$ is then $$\deg(g)\deg(s)+\max_{0\leq i\leq\deg(f)}\{\deg(s)(\deg(f)-i)+i\deg(r)\}\\=\deg(g)\deg(s)+\max_{0\leq i\leq\deg(f)}\{\deg(f)\deg(s)+i(\deg(r)-\deg(s))\}\tag{5}$$

Similarly for $g$,

$$Tg\left(\frac{r}{s}\right)s^{\deg(f)+\deg(g)}=Ts^{\deg(f)}\sum_{j=0}^{\deg(g)}b_js^{\deg(g)-j}r^j\tag{6}$$ with degree:

$$1+\deg(f)\deg(s)+\max_{0\leq j\leq\deg(g)}\{\deg(s)(\deg(g)-j)+j\deg(r)\}\\=1+\deg(f)\deg(s)+\max_{0\leq j\leq\deg(g)}\{\deg(g)\deg(s)+j(\deg(r)-\deg(s))\}\tag{7}$$

All in all, we have $$1+\deg(f)\deg(s)+\max_{0\leq j\leq\deg(g)}\{\deg(g)\deg(s)+j(\deg(r)-\deg(s))\}\\=\deg(g)\deg(s)+\max_{0\leq i\leq\deg(f)}\{\deg(f)\deg(s)+i(\deg(r)-\deg(s))\}\tag{8}$$ which simplifies to $$1=\max_{0\leq i\leq\deg(f)}\{i(\deg(r)-\deg(s))\}-\max_{0\leq j\leq\deg(g)}\{j(\deg(r)-\deg(s))\}\tag{9}$$

There are 3 cases to consider in eq. $(9)$:

1. $\deg(r)>\deg(s)$, in this case the maximum degree occurs when $i=\deg(f), j=\deg(g)$. Rearranging eq. $(9)$ then gives $$1=(\deg(f)-\deg(g))(\deg(r)-\deg(s))\tag{10}$$ This forces $\deg(f)=\deg(g)+1$, $\deg(r)=\deg(s)+1$ and also tells us that it is impossible to have $\deg(f)=\deg(g)$, which sounds wrong.
2. $\deg(r)=\deg(s)$, this case simplifies to $$1=0\tag{11}$$ which is also a contradiction.
3. $\deg(r)<\deg(s)$, this gives exactly the same result as the 2nd. case, since the maximum degree occurs at $i=j=0$.

In particular, eq. $(10)$ does not allow any linear transformation as endomorphisms. This is wrong since any $$\psi(T)=\frac{a_0+a_1T}{b_0+b_1T}\mid a_0b_1-a_1b_0\neq 0\tag{12}$$ has the inverse $$\psi^{-1}(T)=\frac{a_0-b_0T}{-a_1+b_1T}\tag{13}$$ and are therefore endomorphisms with $\deg(f)=\deg(g)$, and $\deg(f)=\deg(g)=\deg(r)=\deg(s)=1$.

I seem to get contradictions in all 3 cases above. I would be very happy if someone could point out my mistakes! I'm very unsure about eq. $(10)$, because it intuitively looks like something one would get, blindly calculating the degrees of the polynomial-eq. $(3)$, that is $\deg(f)(\deg(r)-\deg(s))=1+\deg(g)(\deg(r)-\deg(s))$.

Comment: Aren't you missing $\deg s$ on the first $\deg g$ and $\deg f$ in equations (5) and (7)? Idk if that resolves your problem though.

Comment: @jgon You are right, thank you! I'll calculate again, and update my question!

Comment: @jgon This is interesting, the 2. and 3. case got even worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equality (5) breaks when $\deg (r)=\deg (s)$ and the leading coefficients $l_r$ and $l_s$ of $r$ and $s$ are such that $\frac{l_r}{l_s}$ is a root of $f$:

With  $d=\deg (r)=\deg (s)$ the leading term of $\sum_{i=0}^{\deg(f)}a_is^{\deg(f)-i}r^i$ becomes $$T^{d\deg(f)}\sum_{i=0}^{\deg(f)}a_i{l_s}^{\deg(f)-i}{l_r}^i={l_s}^{\deg(f)}\,T^{d\deg(f)}\sum_{i=0}^{\deg(f)}a_i{(\frac{l_r}{l_s})^i}={l_s}^{\deg(f)}\,T^{d\deg(f)}f(\frac{l_r}{l_s})=0$$

Comment: I can't see how eq. (5) breaks, the degree of every term is then $\deg(s)\deg(f)+\deg(s)\deg(g)$. What are you thinking about?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout I added more details on why the degree of the sum is at least 1 less than expected.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't see why $\frac{l_r}{l_s}$ is a root of $f$. It is clear to me though that $\frac{r(0)}{s(0)}$ is.

Comment: The point is that your steps from (4) to (5) and from (6) to (7) use the assumption that the highest degree terms in the summation in (4) and (6) will never cancel each other, which would lead to a lower degree for the whole sum. But that is exactly what happens for your linear transformations because in that case $g(\frac{l_r}{l_s})=b_0+b_1\frac {-b_0}{b_1}=0$. So for a solid rejection of the non-linear cases your steps from (4) to (5) and from (6) to (7) should explain why those highest degree terms cannot cancel.