# Exercise 0.6ii in Miles Reid's Commutative Algebra (proof verification)

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory, solution-verification, automorphism-group

> Let $K=k(T)$ be the field of rational functions; a *k-automorphism* of $K$ is a ring homomorphism $\phi: K\rightarrow K$ that is the identity on $k$ and is an automorphism of $K$. Describe the group $\text{Aut}_k(K)$ of $k$-automorphisms of $K$.

I've asked a different question about the same exercise [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3556120/413677). I'm looking for a proof verification for this elementary proof.

Let $\phi:K\rightarrow K$ be an automorphism, then $\phi$ is determined by $\phi(T)$ since, for $f,g\in k[T]$, $$\phi\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)=\frac{f(\phi(T))}{g(\phi(T))}\tag{1}$$ Let $\phi(T)=\frac{f}{g}$ with $f,g\in k[T]$, and let $\phi^{-1}(T)=\frac{r}{s}$ with $r,s\in K$. Assume that $f,g$ have no common factor, and the same for $r,s$. Then $$f\left(\frac{r}{s}\right)=Tg\left(\frac{r}{s}\right)\tag{2}$$

Expanding $(2)$ yields,

$$a_n\left(\frac{r}{s}\right)^n+\ldots+a_0=T\left(b_m\left(\frac{r}{s}\right)^m+\ldots+b_0\right)\tag{3}$$

There are 3 cases to consider:

1. If $n>m$ then multiplying $(3)$ by $s^n$ yields $$a_nr^n+\ldots+a_0s^n=T(b_mr^ms^{n-m}+\ldots+b_0s^n)$$ Every term except $a_0s^n, Tb_0s^n$ is divisible by $r$, therefore $r\mid (b_0T-a_0)s^n\Rightarrow r\mid b_0T-a_0$ since $r,s$ have no common factor. Therefore $$r=r_1T+r_0$$ Also, $s\mid a_nr^n\Rightarrow s\mid a_n\Rightarrow s=s_0$. We can swap the role of $\frac{f}{g}$ and $\frac{r}{s}$ since $\phi\circ\phi^{-1}=\phi^{-1}\circ\phi$. Running over the same argument as above, we obtain: $$\boxed{f=f_1T+f_0\\g=g_0\\r=r_1T+r_0\\s=s_0}$$
2. If $n=m$, then arguing the same as is the 1. case yields $$\boxed{f=f_1T+f_0\\g=g_1T+g_0\\r=r_1T+r_0\\s=s_1T+s_0}$$
3. If $n<m$, then arguing the same as is the 1. case yields $$\boxed{f=f_1T+f_0\\g=g_0\\r=r_1T+r_0\\s=s_0}$$

All in all, every automorphism has the form $$\phi(T)=\frac{a+bT}{c+dT}\mid ad-bc\neq 0$$ $ad-bc\neq 0$ since $a+bT\neq k(c+dT)$

Comment: The quoted question is about $K=k(T)$, but your entire question is about $K(T)$ and $K[T]$. Is this supposed to be $k(T)$ and $k[T]$ instead?

Comment: @Servaes You're right, it should be $k(T)$. I'll update the question, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct, as far as I can tell. Some minor comments:

1. Throughout the proof you may want to clarify where  different variables are from; I'm able to infer that variables with subscripts are elements of $k$, but this is not explicitly stated anywhere.
2. In the second case, where $n=m$, you have a typo; you write $s=s_T+s_0$.
3. In your conclusion you may want to clarify why $ad-bc\neq0$. Also here you have a typo; you write $ad-bd\neq0$.